# How do i select max createddate value from a dictionary<ulong, title>

Tags: c#

I wanna select title with latest created date from dictionary.

ulong is the serial for the title and title is a class with "created" as date of creation. I wanna select the title which has been created most recently.

Comment: How about posting a test case  along with what what you have tried so far?

Comment: without code we all guess, but my guess is the key is the date in millisecs after a point in time?  Use a SortedDictionary?  Or Linq, Min()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just OrderByDesending `Title.created` and then take the first one:

```
Title result = dic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.created).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```